# How to avoid domain removal attacks?

Tags: domains, botattack

I see on my website log that someone tried the following URL:

```
GET /domainsigma_removal_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.html HTTP/1.1" 404 188 - "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; OptimizationCrawler/0.2; +http://www.domainoptima.com/robot)"
```

Could anyone explain what does this mean and how can I protect my website against such attacks?

Answer (score 1):

Someone (likely a bot) with the user agent [1] tried to access the resource [2] on your server. Your server responded with status code 404, probably because this resource doesn’t exist.

A simple GET request like this is no reason to assume that an attack is going on.

The bot claims that it’s the [bot "DomainOptimaCralwer" from domainoptima.com](http://www.domainoptima.com/robot) (this doesn’t have to be true), so if you are curious, you could [contact](http://www.domainoptima.com/contact-us) them and ask about it.

[1] `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; OptimizationCrawler/0.2; +http://www.domainoptima.com/robot)`

[2] `/domainsigma_removal_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.html`

Comment: This looks like just another SEO website pinging your site trying to sell you online SEO services. Ignore them. This is just one of "like" a billion.